# Jms deserializer class with parent properties

Tags: php, jmsserializerbundle

I use `"jms/serializer": "^3.3",` stand alone. And my goal create parent class for two child with common properties. I did it. Cretae parent class `Request` and two child - `ApiRequest` and `FormRequest`. Child differ in that they have different serializer names for properties that's all. I use yml mapping.

```
/**
 * Class Request
 */

class Request
{
/**
 * @var SignatureType
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
public $signatureType;
```

Child

```
/**
 * Class ApiRequest
 * @package CDB\Collection\DTO
 * @RequestApplication()
 * @SignatoryTypeConstraint()
 */
class ApiRequest extends Request
{

}
```

and child config `CDB.Collection.DTO.ApiRequest.yml`

```
CDB\Collection\DTO\ApiRequest:
  exclusion_policy: ALL
  properties:
    signatureType:
      expose: true
      type: string
      serialized_name: signatureType
```

For parent I don't have config

and when I try deserialize json

```
{

    "signatureType": "bankid"
}
```

Object have empty property

When I try deserializer json

```
{

    "signature_type": "bankid"
}
```

I determined that metadata for child class did not contain `propertyMetadata. When I remove condtiion in`
jms/serializer/src/Metadata/Driver/YamlDriver.php`
from

```
            foreach ($class->getProperties() as $property) {
                if ($property->class !== $name || (isset($property->info) && $property->info['class'] !== $name)) {
                    continue;
                }
```

to

```
            foreach ($class->getProperties() as $property) {
                if ((isset($property->info) && $property->info['class'] !== $name) {
                    continue;
                }
```

`$metadata` for my class metadata began to contain data about my child class. Because `$class->getProperties()` reflection function which get properties from parent, that's why property class name and class for which metadata generated is different. 
Maybe I select wrong way or who know how to correct work with yml configuration for class whose properties from parent classes ?